# Who is the Yalkut Moshe

Tags: jewish-books

Where can i find information about the author of the [Sefer Yalkut Moshe](https://hebrewbooks.org/9572)?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bio from p. 76 of מחקרים בתולדות יהודי עיראק ובתרבותם

> ר' משה ב"ר ישראל בנימין המכונה "חכם דבש" הוא היה נכד רבנו גרשון גיסו
> של הבעש"ט הוא נסע להודו בשליחות כולל האשכנזים בצפת ושהה בה בשנים תרנ"ד
> תרנ"ה הוא התאכסן בבית סיג עבדאללה ב"ר דוד ששון ושם חיבר את ספרו ילקוט
> משה מונקאטש תרנ"ד ירושלים תשכ"ה בראש ספר זה הוא הודה לאישים ממשפחת
> ששון מעיר בומביי שסייעו לו ו ראלה יעמדו על הברכה השר והטפסר הגנביר
> החסיד עושה חסד לאלפים סנ"י סנ"י עבד אל ב"ר דוד ששון הי"ו כי בהיותי
> בביתו סמוך על שולחנו התחלתי לחבר הספר הזה והרבה עמי חסדים הוא ונוות
> ביתו הצדקת חנה כתון ובנו היקר עירא אשר נשא בת הרב מאיר רוטשילד בעיר
> פאריז והיום כינו שמו באראן עייט ווארט ששון הי"ו ואחיו השר הטפסר החסיד
> סנ"י שלימאן ששת הי"ו וחתנו החה"ש הג' היקר החסיד רודף צדקה וחסד סנ"י
> אטרת משה גמא וז' הצדיקת רחל ובת מלך הצדיקת הג' אשר אין על ספר משלה
> החכמנית בתורה ובגמרא ובצדקתה אין חקר סנ"י סנ"י מזל טוב ששון הי"ו וכל
> בניה למודי ה' וח"ג הג' השר הצדיק יעקב בן אליהו ששת וז' בת הג' הצדיק
> שמעון רפאל חיים הי"ו וה"ג הג' החכם השלם חיים מנכבדי כלכותה שעזרו לו
> הוא מזכיר אישים מיוצאי בבל התה"ש בקי בחדרי תורה עוודה צדקה וחסד עם
> עמלי תורה אליהו חיים הלאלי ובנו החכם הלאלי החה"ש החסיד והכולל המרומם
> אחרת שלום גבאי הגביר הישיש החסיד המרומם רודף צדקה וחסד החה"ש שמעון
> רפאל חיים יצחק החכם ושלם בכל מיני מדע איש טוב וישר נאמן רוח וכשר אוהב
> התורה ולומדיה סנ"י עזרא אחרת שלום גבאי נארח ^ בהיותו בכלכותה הוא פנה
> ביום ג בשבט תרנ"ה מעל דפי השבועון מגיד מישרים כי יקנו את ספרו הנ"ל
> משום שבתמורה הוא רוצה לחתן את בתו הערכה על ספר זה נתפרסמה בשבועון הנ"ל
> מהודו נסע לעדן ושם נפטר ביום כד באלול תרנ"ה (1895)

---

Sorry, no time to translate now